# How can I fix a button at the bottom in the scrollview android?

Tags: android, scrollview, android-linearlayout, android-relativelayout

I have this following layout.

I have a button which comes at the bottom of the screen.

I have put my table layout in the scrollview which is scrolling perfectly.

But using scrollview makes the bottom button disapper.
How can I fix it.

This is my xml layout file

```
   <LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:layout_width="fill_parent"
android:layout_height="fill_parent"
 android:orientation="vertical" >

<LinearLayout
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_marginBottom="50dp"
    android:layout_marginLeft="10dp"
    android:layout_marginRight="10dp"
    android:layout_marginTop="80dp"
    android:orientation="vertical" >

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/textView1"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="61dp"
        android:gravity="center"
        android:text="Interest Rates on Domestic Term Deposits (w.e.f. 26th Septemr, 2013)"
        android:textColor="@color/White" />

    <ScrollView
        android:id="@+id/scrollView1"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="0dip"
        android:layout_weight="1" >

        <TableLayout
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content" >

            <TableRow
                android:id="@+id/tableRow1"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:background="@color/Red"
                android:gravity="center" >

                <TextView
                    android:id="@+id/textView2"
                    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_weight="1"
                    android:gravity="center"
                    android:text="Pariculars"
                    android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceSmall"
                    android:textColor="@color/White" />

                <TextView
                    android:id="@+id/textView3"
                    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_weight="1"
                    android:gravity="center"
                    android:text="General"
                    android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceSmall"
                    android:textColor="@color/White" />

                <TextView
                    android:id="@+id/textView4"
                    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_weight="1"
                    android:gravity="center"
                    android:text="Senior Citizens(p.a.)"
                    android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceSmall"
                    android:textColor="@color/White" />
            </TableRow>

            <TableRow
                android:id="@+id/tableRow2"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:gravity="center" >

                <TextView
                    android:id="@+id/textView3"
                    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_weight="1"
                    android:gravity="center"
                    android:text="Revised for deposit upto"
                    android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceSmall"
                    android:textColor="@color/White" />

                <TextView
                    android:id="@+id/textView4"
                    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_weight="1"
                    android:gravity="center"
                    android:text="Revised for deposit upto"
                    android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceSmall"
                    android:textColor="@color/White" />

                <TextView
                    android:id="@+id/textView5"
                    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_weight="1"
                    android:gravity="center"
                    android:text="Revised for deposit upto"
                    android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceSmall"
                    android:textColor="@color/White" />
            </TableRow>

            <TableRow
                android:id="@+id/tableRow3"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:gravity="center" >

                <TextView
                    android:id="@+id/textView6"
                    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_weight="1"
                    android:gravity="center"
                    android:text="Rs. 15 Lacs"
                    android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceSmall"
                    android:textColor="@color/White" />

                <TextView
                    android:id="@+id/textView7"
                    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_weight="1"
                    android:gravity="center"
                    android:text="Rs. 15 Lacs"
                    android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceSmall"
                    android:textColor="@color/White" />

                <TextView
                    android:id="@+id/textView8"
                    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_weight="1"
                    android:gravity="center"
                    android:text="Rs. 15 Lacs"
                    android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceSmall"
                    android:textColor="@color/White" />
            </TableRow>

            <TableRow
                android:id="@+id/tableRow4"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:gravity="center" >

                <TextView
                    android:id="@+id/textView9"
                    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_weight="1"
                    android:gravity="center"
                    android:text="7days to 14 days"
                    android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceSmall"
                    android:textColor="@color/White" />

                <TextView
                    android:id="@+id/textView10"
                    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_weight="1"
                    android:gravity="center"
                    android:text="7.25%"
                    android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceSmall"
                    android:textColor="@color/White" />

                <TextView
                    android:id="@+id/textView11"
                    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_weight="1"
                    android:gravity="center"
                    android:text="7.25%"
                    android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceSmall"
                    android:textColor="@color/White" />
            </TableRow>

            <TableRow
                android:id="@+id/tableRow5"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:gravity="center" >

                <TextView
                    android:id="@+id/textView12"
                    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_weight="1"
                    android:gravity="center"
                    android:text="15 days to 90 days"
                    android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceSmall"
                    android:textColor="@color/White" />

                <TextView
                    android:id="@+id/textView13"
                    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_weight="1"
                    android:gravity="center"
                    android:text="7.75%"
                    android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceSmall"
                    android:textColor="@color/White" />

                <TextView
                    android:id="@+id/textView14"
                    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_weight="1"
                    android:gravity="center"
                    android:text="7.75%"
                    android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceSmall"
                    android:textColor="@color/White" />
            </TableRow>

            <TableRow
                android:id="@+id/tableRow6"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:gravity="center" >

                <TextView
                    android:id="@+id/textView15"
                    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_weight="1"
                    android:gravity="center"
                    android:text="91 days to 180 days"
                    android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceSmall"
                    android:textColor="@color/White" />

                <TextView
                    android:id="@+id/textView16"
                    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_weight="1"
                    android:gravity="center"
                    android:text="8.50%"
                    android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceSmall"
                    android:textColor="@color/White" />

                <TextView
                    android:id="@+id/textView17"
                    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_weight="1"
                    android:gravity="center"
                    android:text="8.50%"
                    android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceSmall"
                    android:textColor="@color/White" />
            </TableRow>

            <TableRow
                android:id="@+id/tableRow7"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:gravity="center" >

                <TextView
                    android:id="@+id/textView18"
                    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_weight="1"
                    android:gravity="center"
                    android:text="181 days to 12 months"
                    android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceSmall"
                    android:textColor="@color/White" />

                <TextView
                    android:id="@+id/textView19"
                    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_weight="1"
                    android:gravity="center"
                    android:text="9.50%"
                    android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceSmall"
                    android:textColor="@color/White" />

                <TextView
                    android:id="@+id/textView20"
                    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_weight="1"
                    android:gravity="center"
                    android:text="9.50%"
                    android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceSmall"
                    android:textColor="@color/White" />
            </TableRow>
        </TableLayout>
    </ScrollView>
</LinearLayout>

<RelativeLayout
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:gravity="bottom" >

    <Button
        android:id="@+id/homeInterestButton"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
        android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
        android:text="Home" />
</RelativeLayout>
```

I just need my tablelayout content to be scrollable and the homebutton should come at the bottom of the activity.

Comment: Put the RelativeLayout below `</ScrollView>`

Comment: FrameLayout with two children: a ScrollView and a Button is your friend

Comment: @RickFalck already tried but not working

Comment: @pskink `RelativeLayout` with two children : `ScrollView` and  `Button` is OP's *best* friend. Your argument is invalid ! xD

Comment: @LittleChild RelativeLayout is better in this case? any reason? speed? memory usage? any other?

Comment: @pskink Relax... it was a joke xD

Comment: Are you sure want to put it on the bottom of your ScrollView?

Comment: No not the bottom of scrollview but bottom of the activity.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

@Shink
Check this removed -- weight -- from scrollview and replaced 0dp to wrap_content, changed the parent to relative layout, and button without having its container relativelayout:

```
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="fill_parent"
    android:background="@android:color/darker_gray"
    android:orientation="vertical" >

    <LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_marginBottom="50dp"
        android:layout_marginLeft="10dp"
        android:layout_marginRight="10dp"
        android:layout_marginTop="80dp"
        android:orientation="vertical" >

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/textView1"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="61dp"
            android:gravity="center"
            android:text="Interest Rates on Domestic Term Deposits (w.e.f. 26th Septemr, 2013)"
            android:textColor="@android:color/white" />

        <ScrollView
            android:id="@+id/scrollView1"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content" >

            <TableLayout
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content" >

                <TableRow
                    android:id="@+id/tableRow1"
                    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:background="@android:color/black"
                    android:gravity="center" >

                    <TextView
                        android:id="@+id/textView2"
                        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                        android:layout_weight="1"
                        android:gravity="center"
                        android:text="Pariculars"
                        android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceSmall"
                        android:textColor="@android:color/white" />

                    <TextView
                        android:id="@+id/textView3"
                        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                        android:layout_weight="1"
                        android:gravity="center"
                        android:text="General"
                        android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceSmall"
                        android:textColor="@android:color/white" />

                    <TextView
                        android:id="@+id/textView4"
                        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                        android:layout_weight="1"
                        android:gravity="center"
                        android:text="Senior Citizens(p.a.)"
                        android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceSmall"
                        android:textColor="@android:color/white" />
                </TableRow>

                <TableRow
                    android:id="@+id/tableRow2"
                    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:gravity="center" >

                    <TextView
                        android:id="@+id/textView3"
                        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                        android:layout_weight="1"
                        android:gravity="center"
                        android:text="Revised for deposit upto"
                        android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceSmall"
                        android:textColor="@android:color/white" />

                    <TextView
                        android:id="@+id/textView4"
                        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                        android:layout_weight="1"
                        android:gravity="center"
                        android:text="Revised for deposit upto"
                        android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceSmall"
                        android:textColor="@android:color/white" />

                    <TextView
                        android:id="@+id/textView5"
                        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                        android:layout_weight="1"
                        android:gravity="center"
                        android:text="Revised for deposit upto"
                        android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceSmall"
                        android:textColor="@android:color/white" />
                </TableRow>

                <TableRow
                    android:id="@+id/tableRow3"
                    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:gravity="center" >

                    <TextView
                        android:id="@+id/textView6"
                        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                        android:layout_weight="1"
                        android:gravity="center"
                        android:text="Rs. 15 Lacs"
                        android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceSmall"
                        android:textColor="@android:color/white" />

                    <TextView
                        android:id="@+id/textView7"
                        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                        android:layout_weight="1"
                        android:gravity="center"
                        android:text="Rs. 15 Lacs"
                        android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceSmall"
                        android:textColor="@android:color/white" />

                    <TextView
                        android:id="@+id/textView8"
                        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                        android:layout_weight="1"
                        android:gravity="center"
                        android:text="Rs. 15 Lacs"
                        android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceSmall"
                        android:textColor="@android:color/white" />
                </TableRow>

                <TableRow
                    android:id="@+id/tableRow4"
                    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:gravity="center" >

                    <TextView
                        android:id="@+id/textView9"
                        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                        android:layout_weight="1"
                        android:gravity="center"
                        android:text="7days to 14 days"
                        android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceSmall"
                        android:textColor="@android:color/white" />

                    <TextView
                        android:id="@+id/textView10"
                        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                        android:layout_weight="1"
                        android:gravity="center"
                        android:text="7.25%"
                        android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceSmall"
                        android:textColor="@android:color/white" />

                    <TextView
                        android:id="@+id/textView11"
                        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                        android:layout_weight="1"
                        android:gravity="center"
                        android:text="7.25%"
                        android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceSmall"
                        android:textColor="@android:color/white" />
                </TableRow>

                <TableRow
                    android:id="@+id/tableRow5"
                    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:gravity="center" >

                    <TextView
                        android:id="@+id/textView12"
                        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                        android:layout_weight="1"
                        android:gravity="center"
                        android:text="15 days to 90 days"
                        android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceSmall"
                        android:textColor="@android:color/white" />

                    <TextView
                        android:id="@+id/textView13"
                        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                        android:layout_weight="1"
                        android:gravity="center"
                        android:text="7.75%"
                        android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceSmall"
                        android:textColor="@android:color/white" />

                    <TextView
                        android:id="@+id/textView14"
                        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                        android:layout_weight="1"
                        android:gravity="center"
                        android:text="7.75%"
                        android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceSmall"
                        android:textColor="@android:color/white" />
                </TableRow>

                <TableRow
                    android:id="@+id/tableRow6"
                    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:gravity="center" >

                    <TextView
                        android:id="@+id/textView15"
                        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                        android:layout_weight="1"
                        android:gravity="center"
                        android:text="91 days to 180 days"
                        android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceSmall"
                        android:textColor="@android:color/white" />

                    <TextView
                        android:id="@+id/textView16"
                        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                        android:layout_weight="1"
                        android:gravity="center"
                        android:text="8.50%"
                        android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceSmall"
                        android:textColor="@android:color/white" />

                    <TextView
                        android:id="@+id/textView17"
                        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                        android:layout_weight="1"
                        android:gravity="center"
                        android:text="8.50%"
                        android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceSmall"
                        android:textColor="@android:color/white" />
                </TableRow>

                <TableRow
                    android:id="@+id/tableRow7"
                    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:gravity="center" >

                    <TextView
                        android:id="@+id/textView18"
                        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                        android:layout_weight="1"
                        android:gravity="center"
                        android:text="181 days to 12 months"
                        android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceSmall"
                        android:textColor="@android:color/white" />

                    <TextView
                        android:id="@+id/textView19"
                        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                        android:layout_weight="1"
                        android:gravity="center"
                        android:text="9.50%"
                        android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceSmall"
                        android:textColor="@android:color/white" />

                    <TextView
                        android:id="@+id/textView20"
                        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                        android:layout_weight="1"
                        android:gravity="center"
                        android:text="9.50%"
                        android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceSmall"
                        android:textColor="@android:color/white" />
                </TableRow>
            </TableLayout>
        </ScrollView>
    </LinearLayout>

    <Button
        android:id="@+id/homeInterestButton"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
        android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
        android:text="Home" />

</RelativeLayout>
```

Answer (score 4):

add `android:fillViewport="true"` attribute for your `ScrollView`. See the code below.

```
<ScrollView
        android:id="@+id/scrollView1"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="0dip"
        android:fillViewport="true"
        android:layout_weight="1" >
```

also change the code like below.

```
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="fill_parent"
    android:orientation="vertical" >

    <LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_marginBottom="50dp"
        android:layout_marginLeft="10dp"
        android:layout_marginRight="10dp"
        android:layout_marginTop="80dp"
        android:orientation="vertical" >

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/textView1"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="61dp"
            android:gravity="center"
            android:text="Interest Rates on Domestic Term Deposits (w.e.f. 26th Septemr, 2013)"
            android:textColor="@color/White" />

        <ScrollView
            android:id="@+id/scrollView1"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="0dip"
            android:layout_weight="1" >

            <TableLayout
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content" >

                <TableRow
                    android:id="@+id/tableRow1"
                    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:background="@color/Red"
                    android:gravity="center" >

                    <TextView
                        android:id="@+id/textView2"
                        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                        android:layout_weight="1"
                        android:gravity="center"
                        android:text="Pariculars"
                        android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceSmall"
                        android:textColor="@color/White" />

                    <TextView
                        android:id="@+id/textView3"
                        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                        android:layout_weight="1"
                        android:gravity="center"
                        android:text="General"
                        android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceSmall"
                        android:textColor="@color/White" />

                    <TextView
                        android:id="@+id/textView4"
                        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                        android:layout_weight="1"
                        android:gravity="center"
                        android:text="Senior Citizens(p.a.)"
                        android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceSmall"
                        android:textColor="@color/White" />
                </TableRow>

                <TableRow
                    android:id="@+id/tableRow2"
                    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:gravity="center" >

                    <TextView
                        android:id="@+id/textView3"
                        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                        android:layout_weight="1"
                        android:gravity="center"
                        android:text="Revised for deposit upto"
                        android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceSmall"
                        android:textColor="@color/White" />

                    <TextView
                        android:id="@+id/textView4"
                        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                        android:layout_weight="1"
                        android:gravity="center"
                        android:text="Revised for deposit upto"
                        android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceSmall"
                        android:textColor="@color/White" />

                    <TextView
                        android:id="@+id/textView5"
                        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                        android:layout_weight="1"
                        android:gravity="center"
                        android:text="Revised for deposit upto"
                        android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceSmall"
                        android:textColor="@color/White" />
                </TableRow>

                <TableRow
                    android:id="@+id/tableRow3"
                    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:gravity="center" >

                    <TextView
                        android:id="@+id/textView6"
                        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                        android:layout_weight="1"
                        android:gravity="center"
                        android:text="Rs. 15 Lacs"
                        android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceSmall"
                        android:textColor="@color/White" />

                    <TextView
                        android:id="@+id/textView7"
                        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                        android:layout_weight="1"
                        android:gravity="center"
                        android:text="Rs. 15 Lacs"
                        android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceSmall"
                        android:textColor="@color/White" />

                    <TextView
                        android:id="@+id/textView8"
                        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                        android:layout_weight="1"
                        android:gravity="center"
                        android:text="Rs. 15 Lacs"
                        android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceSmall"
                        android:textColor="@color/White" />
                </TableRow>

                <TableRow
                    android:id="@+id/tableRow4"
                    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:gravity="center" >

                    <TextView
                        android:id="@+id/textView9"
                        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                        android:layout_weight="1"
                        android:gravity="center"
                        android:text="7days to 14 days"
                        android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceSmall"
                        android:textColor="@color/White" />

                    <TextView
                        android:id="@+id/textView10"
                        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                        android:layout_weight="1"
                        android:gravity="center"
                        android:text="7.25%"
                        android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceSmall"
                        android:textColor="@color/White" />

                    <TextView
                        android:id="@+id/textView11"
                        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                        android:layout_weight="1"
                        android:gravity="center"
                        android:text="7.25%"
                        android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceSmall"
                        android:textColor="@color/White" />
                </TableRow>

                <TableRow
                    android:id="@+id/tableRow5"
                    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:gravity="center" >

                    <TextView
                        android:id="@+id/textView12"
                        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                        android:layout_weight="1"
                        android:gravity="center"
                        android:text="15 days to 90 days"
                        android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceSmall"
                        android:textColor="@color/White" />

                    <TextView
                        android:id="@+id/textView13"
                        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                        android:layout_weight="1"
                        android:gravity="center"
                        android:text="7.75%"
                        android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceSmall"
                        android:textColor="@color/White" />

                    <TextView
                        android:id="@+id/textView14"
                        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                        android:layout_weight="1"
                        android:gravity="center"
                        android:text="7.75%"
                        android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceSmall"
                        android:textColor="@color/White" />
                </TableRow>

                <TableRow
                    android:id="@+id/tableRow6"
                    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:gravity="center" >

                    <TextView
                        android:id="@+id/textView15"
                        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                        android:layout_weight="1"
                        android:gravity="center"
                        android:text="91 days to 180 days"
                        android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceSmall"
                        android:textColor="@color/White" />

                    <TextView
                        android:id="@+id/textView16"
                        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                        android:layout_weight="1"
                        android:gravity="center"
                        android:text="8.50%"
                        android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceSmall"
                        android:textColor="@color/White" />

                    <TextView
                        android:id="@+id/textView17"
                        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                        android:layout_weight="1"
                        android:gravity="center"
                        android:text="8.50%"
                        android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceSmall"
                        android:textColor="@color/White" />
                </TableRow>

                <TableRow
                    android:id="@+id/tableRow7"
                    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:gravity="center" >

                    <TextView
                        android:id="@+id/textView18"
                        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                        android:layout_weight="1"
                        android:gravity="center"
                        android:text="181 days to 12 months"
                        android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceSmall"
                        android:textColor="@color/White" />

                    <TextView
                        android:id="@+id/textView19"
                        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                        android:layout_weight="1"
                        android:gravity="center"
                        android:text="9.50%"
                        android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceSmall"
                        android:textColor="@color/White" />

                    <TextView
                        android:id="@+id/textView20"
                        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                        android:layout_weight="1"
                        android:gravity="center"
                        android:text="9.50%"
                        android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceSmall"
                        android:textColor="@color/White" />
                </TableRow>
            </TableLayout>
        </ScrollView>

        <RelativeLayout
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:gravity="bottom" >

            <Button
                android:id="@+id/homeInterestButton"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
                android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
                android:text="Home" />
        </RelativeLayout>
    </LinearLayout>
</LinearLayout>
```

Comment: not working. I just need my tablelayout content to be scrollable and the homebutton should come at the bottom.

Answer (score 2):

Put below 2 lines in the 2nd Top Linear layout And you are done:

```
        android:layout_height="0dp"
        android:layout_weight="1"
```

In short What you have to do is put the below xml in your project and run it.

```
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="fill_parent"
    android:orientation="vertical"
    android:background="#000" >

    <LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="0dp"
        android:layout_weight="1"
        android:layout_marginLeft="10dp"
        android:layout_marginRight="10dp"
        android:layout_marginTop="80dp"
        android:layout_marginBottom="50dp" 
        android:orientation="vertical" >

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/textView1"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="61dp"
            android:gravity="center"
            android:text="Interest Rates on Domestic Term Deposits (w.e.f. 26th Septemr, 2013)"
            android:textColor="@android:color/white" />

        <ScrollView
            android:id="@+id/scrollView1"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="0dip"
            android:layout_weight="1" >

            <TableLayout
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content" >

                <TableRow
                    android:id="@+id/tableRow1"
                    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:background="#900"
                    android:gravity="center" >

                    <TextView
                        android:id="@+id/textView2"
                        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                        android:layout_weight="1"
                        android:gravity="center"
                        android:text="Pariculars"
                        android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceSmall"
                        android:textColor="@android:color/white" />

                    <TextView
                        android:id="@+id/textView3"
                        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                        android:layout_weight="1"
                        android:gravity="center"
                        android:text="General"
                        android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceSmall"
                        android:textColor="@android:color/white" />

                    <TextView
                        android:id="@+id/textView4"
                        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                        android:layout_weight="1"
                        android:gravity="center"
                        android:text="Senior Citizens(p.a.)"
                        android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceSmall"
                        android:textColor="@android:color/white" />
                </TableRow>

                <TableRow
                    android:id="@+id/tableRow2"
                    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:gravity="center" >

                    <TextView
                        android:id="@+id/textView3"
                        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                        android:layout_weight="1"
                        android:gravity="center"
                        android:text="Revised for deposit upto"
                        android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceSmall"
                        android:textColor="@android:color/white" />

                    <TextView
                        android:id="@+id/textView4"
                        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                        android:layout_weight="1"
                        android:gravity="center"
                        android:text="Revised for deposit upto"
                        android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceSmall"
                        android:textColor="@android:color/white" />

                    <TextView
                        android:id="@+id/textView5"
                        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                        android:layout_weight="1"
                        android:gravity="center"
                        android:text="Revised for deposit upto"
                        android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceSmall"
                        android:textColor="@android:color/white" />
                </TableRow>

                <TableRow
                    android:id="@+id/tableRow3"
                    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:gravity="center" >

                    <TextView
                        android:id="@+id/textView6"
                        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                        android:layout_weight="1"
                        android:gravity="center"
                        android:text="Rs. 15 Lacs"
                        android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceSmall"
                        android:textColor="@android:color/white" />

                    <TextView
                        android:id="@+id/textView7"
                        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                        android:layout_weight="1"
                        android:gravity="center"
                        android:text="Rs. 15 Lacs"
                        android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceSmall"
                        android:textColor="@android:color/white" />

                    <TextView
                        android:id="@+id/textView8"
                        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                        android:layout_weight="1"
                        android:gravity="center"
                        android:text="Rs. 15 Lacs"
                        android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceSmall"
                        android:textColor="@android:color/white" />
                </TableRow>

                <TableRow
                    android:id="@+id/tableRow4"
                    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:gravity="center" >

                    <TextView
                        android:id="@+id/textView9"
                        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                        android:layout_weight="1"
                        android:gravity="center"
                        android:text="7days to 14 days"
                        android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceSmall"
                        android:textColor="@android:color/white" />

                    <TextView
                        android:id="@+id/textView10"
                        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                        android:layout_weight="1"
                        android:gravity="center"
                        android:text="7.25%"
                        android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceSmall"
                        android:textColor="@android:color/white" />

                    <TextView
                        android:id="@+id/textView11"
                        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                        android:layout_weight="1"
                        android:gravity="center"
                        android:text="7.25%"
                        android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceSmall"
                        android:textColor="@android:color/white" />
                </TableRow>

                <TableRow
                    android:id="@+id/tableRow5"
                    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:gravity="center" >

                    <TextView
                        android:id="@+id/textView12"
                        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                        android:layout_weight="1"
                        android:gravity="center"
                        android:text="15 days to 90 days"
                        android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceSmall"
                        android:textColor="@android:color/white" />

                    <TextView
                        android:id="@+id/textView13"
                        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                        android:layout_weight="1"
                        android:gravity="center"
                        android:text="7.75%"
                        android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceSmall"
                        android:textColor="@android:color/white" />

                    <TextView
                        android:id="@+id/textView14"
                        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                        android:layout_weight="1"
                        android:gravity="center"
                        android:text="7.75%"
                        android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceSmall"
                        android:textColor="@android:color/white" />
                </TableRow>

                <TableRow
                    android:id="@+id/tableRow6"
                    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:gravity="center" >

                    <TextView
                        android:id="@+id/textView15"
                        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                        android:layout_weight="1"
                        android:gravity="center"
                        android:text="91 days to 180 days"
                        android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceSmall"
                        android:textColor="@android:color/white" />

                    <TextView
                        android:id="@+id/textView16"
                        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                        android:layout_weight="1"
                        android:gravity="center"
                        android:text="8.50%"
                        android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceSmall"
                        android:textColor="@android:color/white" />

                    <TextView
                        android:id="@+id/textView17"
                        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                        android:layout_weight="1"
                        android:gravity="center"
                        android:text="8.50%"
                        android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceSmall"
                        android:textColor="@android:color/white" />
                </TableRow>

                <TableRow
                    android:id="@+id/tableRow7"
                    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:gravity="center" >

                    <TextView
                        android:id="@+id/textView18"
                        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                        android:layout_weight="1"
                        android:gravity="center"
                        android:text="181 days to 12 months"
                        android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceSmall"
                        android:textColor="@android:color/white" />

                    <TextView
                        android:id="@+id/textView19"
                        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                        android:layout_weight="1"
                        android:gravity="center"
                        android:text="9.50%"
                        android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceSmall"
                        android:textColor="@android:color/white" />

                    <TextView
                        android:id="@+id/textView20"
                        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                        android:layout_weight="1"
                        android:gravity="center"
                        android:text="9.50%"
                        android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceSmall"
                        android:textColor="@android:color/white" />
                </TableRow>
                <TableRow
                    android:id="@+id/tableRow1"
                    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:background="#900"
                    android:gravity="center" >

                    <TextView
                        android:id="@+id/textView2"
                        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                        android:layout_weight="1"
                        android:gravity="center"
                        android:text="Pariculars"
                        android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceSmall"
                        android:textColor="@android:color/white" />

                    <TextView
                        android:id="@+id/textView3"
                        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                        android:layout_weight="1"
                        android:gravity="center"
                        android:text="General"
                        android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceSmall"
                        android:textColor="@android:color/white" />

                    <TextView
                        android:id="@+id/textView4"
                        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                        android:layout_weight="1"
                        android:gravity="center"
                        android:text="Senior Citizens(p.a.)"
                        android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceSmall"
                        android:textColor="@android:color/white" />
                </TableRow><TableRow
                    android:id="@+id/tableRow1"
                    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:background="#900"
                    android:gravity="center" >

                    <TextView
                        android:id="@+id/textView2"
                        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                        android:layout_weight="1"
                        android:gravity="center"
                        android:text="Pariculars"
                        android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceSmall"
                        android:textColor="@android:color/white" />

                    <TextView
                        android:id="@+id/textView3"
                        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                        android:layout_weight="1"
                        android:gravity="center"
                        android:text="General"
                        android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceSmall"
                        android:textColor="@android:color/white" />

                    <TextView
                        android:id="@+id/textView4"
                        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                        android:layout_weight="1"
                        android:gravity="center"
                        android:text="Senior Citizens(p.a.)"
                        android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceSmall"
                        android:textColor="@android:color/white" />
                </TableRow><TableRow
                    android:id="@+id/tableRow1"
                    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:background="#900"
                    android:gravity="center" >

                    <TextView
                        android:id="@+id/textView2"
                        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                        android:layout_weight="1"
                        android:gravity="center"
                        android:text="Pariculars"
                        android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceSmall"
                        android:textColor="@android:color/white" />

                    <TextView
                        android:id="@+id/textView3"
                        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                        android:layout_weight="1"
                        android:gravity="center"
                        android:text="General"
                        android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceSmall"
                        android:textColor="@android:color/white" />

                    <TextView
                        android:id="@+id/textView4"
                        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                        android:layout_weight="1"
                        android:gravity="center"
                        android:text="Senior Citizens(p.a.)"
                        android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceSmall"
                        android:textColor="@android:color/white" />
                </TableRow>
            </TableLayout>
        </ScrollView>
    </LinearLayout>

    <RelativeLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
         android:gravity="center">

        <Button
            android:id="@+id/homeInterestButton"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:text="Home" />
    </RelativeLayout>

</RelativeLayout>
```

Answer (score 1):

Well, you will need to put your button out of `ScrollView`. So there will be another level of nesting needed. Put your `ScrollView` in a `RelativeLayout` (or `LinearLayout`), put the button at the bottom. That way it wont scroll down as items are added to the `ScrollView`

```
<RelativeLayout ...>

    <ScrollView android:id="@+id/scroll"...>
        <!-- The child of ScrollView -->
    </ScrollView>

    <Button android:layout_alignParentBottom = "true"
        android:layout_below="@id/scroll" />

</RelativeLayout>
```

Comment: i didnt get you...can you brief abt it

Answer (score 1):

Hope this works for you:

```
  <LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:layout_width="fill_parent"
android:layout_height="fill_parent"
 android:orientation="vertical" >

<LinearLayout
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_marginBottom="50dp"
    android:layout_marginLeft="10dp"
    android:layout_marginRight="10dp"
    android:layout_marginTop="80dp"
    android:orientation="vertical" >

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/textView1"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="61dp"
        android:gravity="center"
        android:text="Interest Rates on Domestic Term Deposits (w.e.f. 26th Septemr, 2013)"
        android:textColor="@color/White" />

    <ScrollView
        android:id="@+id/scrollView1"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="0dip"
        android:layout_weight="1" >

        <TableLayout
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content" >

            <TableRow
                android:id="@+id/tableRow1"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:background="@color/Red"
                android:gravity="center" >

                <TextView
                    android:id="@+id/textView2"
                    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_weight="1"
                    android:gravity="center"
                    android:text="Pariculars"
                    android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceSmall"
                    android:textColor="@color/White" />

                <TextView
                    android:id="@+id/textView3"
                    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_weight="1"
                    android:gravity="center"
                    android:text="General"
                    android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceSmall"
                    android:textColor="@color/White" />

                <TextView
                    android:id="@+id/textView4"
                    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_weight="1"
                    android:gravity="center"
                    android:text="Senior Citizens(p.a.)"
                    android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceSmall"
                    android:textColor="@color/White" />
            </TableRow>

            <TableRow
                android:id="@+id/tableRow2"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:gravity="center" >

                <TextView
                    android:id="@+id/textView3"
                    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_weight="1"
                    android:gravity="center"
                    android:text="Revised for deposit upto"
                    android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceSmall"
                    android:textColor="@color/White" />

                <TextView
                    android:id="@+id/textView4"
                    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_weight="1"
                    android:gravity="center"
                    android:text="Revised for deposit upto"
                    android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceSmall"
                    android:textColor="@color/White" />

                <TextView
                    android:id="@+id/textView5"
                    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_weight="1"
                    android:gravity="center"
                    android:text="Revised for deposit upto"
                    android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceSmall"
                    android:textColor="@color/White" />
            </TableRow>

            <TableRow
                android:id="@+id/tableRow3"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:gravity="center" >

                <TextView
                    android:id="@+id/textView6"
                    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_weight="1"
                    android:gravity="center"
                    android:text="Rs. 15 Lacs"
                    android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceSmall"
                    android:textColor="@color/White" />

                <TextView
                    android:id="@+id/textView7"
                    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_weight="1"
                    android:gravity="center"
                    android:text="Rs. 15 Lacs"
                    android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceSmall"
                    android:textColor="@color/White" />

                <TextView
                    android:id="@+id/textView8"
                    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_weight="1"
                    android:gravity="center"
                    android:text="Rs. 15 Lacs"
                    android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceSmall"
                    android:textColor="@color/White" />
            </TableRow>

            <TableRow
                android:id="@+id/tableRow4"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:gravity="center" >

                <TextView
                    android:id="@+id/textView9"
                    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_weight="1"
                    android:gravity="center"
                    android:text="7days to 14 days"
                    android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceSmall"
                    android:textColor="@color/White" />

                <TextView
                    android:id="@+id/textView10"
                    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_weight="1"
                    android:gravity="center"
                    android:text="7.25%"
                    android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceSmall"
                    android:textColor="@color/White" />

                <TextView
                    android:id="@+id/textView11"
                    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_weight="1"
                    android:gravity="center"
                    android:text="7.25%"
                    android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceSmall"
                    android:textColor="@color/White" />
            </TableRow>

            <TableRow
                android:id="@+id/tableRow5"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:gravity="center" >

                <TextView
                    android:id="@+id/textView12"
                    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_weight="1"
                    android:gravity="center"
                    android:text="15 days to 90 days"
                    android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceSmall"
                    android:textColor="@color/White" />

                <TextView
                    android:id="@+id/textView13"
                    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_weight="1"
                    android:gravity="center"
                    android:text="7.75%"
                    android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceSmall"
                    android:textColor="@color/White" />

                <TextView
                    android:id="@+id/textView14"
                    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_weight="1"
                    android:gravity="center"
                    android:text="7.75%"
                    android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceSmall"
                    android:textColor="@color/White" />
            </TableRow>

            <TableRow
                android:id="@+id/tableRow6"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:gravity="center" >

                <TextView
                    android:id="@+id/textView15"
                    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_weight="1"
                    android:gravity="center"
                    android:text="91 days to 180 days"
                    android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceSmall"
                    android:textColor="@color/White" />

                <TextView
                    android:id="@+id/textView16"
                    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_weight="1"
                    android:gravity="center"
                    android:text="8.50%"
                    android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceSmall"
                    android:textColor="@color/White" />

                <TextView
                    android:id="@+id/textView17"
                    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_weight="1"
                    android:gravity="center"
                    android:text="8.50%"
                    android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceSmall"
                    android:textColor="@color/White" />
            </TableRow>

            <TableRow
                android:id="@+id/tableRow7"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:gravity="center" >

                <TextView
                    android:id="@+id/textView18"
                    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_weight="1"
                    android:gravity="center"
                    android:text="181 days to 12 months"
                    android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceSmall"
                    android:textColor="@color/White" />

                <TextView
                    android:id="@+id/textView19"
                    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_weight="1"
                    android:gravity="center"
                    android:text="9.50%"
                    android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceSmall"
                    android:textColor="@color/White" />

                <TextView
                    android:id="@+id/textView20"
                    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_weight="1"
                    android:gravity="center"
                    android:text="9.50%"
                    android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceSmall"
                    android:textColor="@color/White" />
            </TableRow>
            <RelativeLayout
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:gravity="bottom" >

    <Button
        android:id="@+id/homeInterestButton"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
        android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
        android:text="Home" />
</RelativeLayout>
        </TableLayout>
    </ScrollView>
</LinearLayout>

</LinearLayout>
```

Comment: not working. I just need my tablelayout content to be scrollable and the homebutton should come at the bottom of the screen.

Answer (score 0):

Your root layout is LinearLayout. Give your button's layout 0 weight and give other layout weight 1. It should do the job.

Comment: What is its behaviour? Can you post the screenshot.